# Query for Coverage of Flow

Tags: code-coverage, visual-workflow

I am trying to find out the test coverage for a stand alone flow.  I have a simple test class built, but I'm not sure where to run the coverage query.  I came across the query below from the SFDC Winter '19 release notes, but I'm not sure where to run it.  Can anyone point me to the right place?

```
SELECT Id, ApexTestClassId, TestMethodName, FlowVersionId, NumElementsCovered, NumElementsNotCovered 
FROM FlowTestCoverage 
WHERE flowversionid='301RM0000004GiK'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the Developer Console by going to the top right similar to here:
[image]

Once there you will find a tab at the bottom called query editor, click that and enter your query and press execute, once its run you should be able to see the returned information directly in the console.

Comment: Thanks.  Got it there and gave me an error, but at least I know where to run it.  Thanks!